# Error: Protocol error (Fetch.continueRequest): Invalid InterceptionId

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am using Puppeteer and chrome dev tools to intercept network responses and modify them if necessary. I use the following code.

```js
const client = page._client;
await client.send("Fetch.enable", {
    patterns: [{ requestStage: "Response" }]
});

client.on("Fetch.requestPaused", async event => {
    const { requestId, request, responseStatusCode, responseErrorReason } = event;
    console.log(`Request "${requestId}" ${responseStatusCode} ${responseErrorReason} ${request.url} paused.`);
    const responseCdp = await client.send("Fetch.getResponseBody", { requestId });
    // TODO Modify response
    await client.send("Fetch.continueRequest", { requestId });
});
```

But this fails intermittently (like 50 % of the time) with the following error

```
Error: Protocol error (Fetch.continueRequest): Invalid InterceptionId.
```

What could possibly cause this issue ?

Comment: Got the same error message when using Fetch.fulfillRequest. In my case, it was due to the request having already been handled by another overlapping RequestPattern.

So watch your urlPatterns, `"http://example/*"` and `"http://example?*"` will overlap. You have to escape the query parameter character like so `"http://example\\?*"`.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out I had made a set of mistakes

1. Some of the resources I was loading was not valid, like the file path did not exist and file format was not correct and so on.
2. I realised I had 2 instances of `page.goto` in my code, which was messing up the interceptor.

Correcting them resolve this issue. What came in handy was to run puppetter with `headless: false` and inspecting the network of of chromium.